# Monitor Bluetooth Peripheral Commands

Tags: c#, bluetooth, iot, windowsiot

I am developing a little Windows IOT application on a Raspberry Pi 3 and I have purchased this Bluetooth device:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00WDARWRY/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00WDARWRY)

I want to be able to listen for the Bluetooth device commands and handle them in my UWP.

Comment: What did you do? What problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, though I was not able to get all of the functionality, especially the Gamepad mode.

The solution was to listen to the device keys entered in with:

```
public MainPage()
        {

            Window.Current.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;

            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher sender, Windows.UI.Core.AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
        {
            var eT = args.EventType;
            if (CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType.KeyUp == eT)
            {
                var key = args.VirtualKey.ToString();
                switch (key)
                {
                    case "Enter" :
                        //Do something
                        break;
                    case "255" :
                        //Do something
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I have found that the keys that are assigned an integer are quite difficult to compare against since there is seemingly no virtual key registered for them. So I convert the virtual key to a string to the comparison.

I find the integer values differ from device to device, so "255" might be "175" in another setup. I hope it doesn't vary from startup to startup...

So to sum it up, this is an acceptable solution for my needs. I do feel as though either writing my own driver for the device may be the best situation but I don't have the time to do that in this project, nor the will right now to learn the subtilties of p/invoke and HID objects.